# Audio / Volume Levels Not Remembered After Reboot

Tags: sound, virtualbox, 19.04

Hi I am running a version of Ubuntu 19.04 Disco Dingo on my computer, in a virtual machine, but I am running into problems where my system is not remembering volume levels like previous builds.For example, when I would run Bionic after restarting the machine, but that through Ubuntu itself, or from the VM manager the settings would stay where I set them (ie. 100%).

Does anyone have any recommendations or a solution to this problem, I don't seem to have this issue with other distros so I am not sure if it is just a bug in this current version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

So I found an answer on reddit from resharing. Credit to u/JeffJ_1 for the solution:

[Audio Volume Levels not remembered after reboot](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/bk5czo/audio_volume_levels_not_remembered_after_reboot/)